# Problems configuring Meschach on Ubuntu 16.10 x64

Tags: c, configure, meschach

I'm new-ish to C.  I am trying to do some matrix manipulation in JavaScript and wanted to embed a C library as a Node JS module.  I finished a proof-of-concept module that does this and is working fine.

I downloaded Meschach from [here (mesch12b.tar.gz)](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~dstewart/meschach/) to do matrix manipulation.  It looks like a good option for what I need (though I'm open to other options in C or C++).

For some reason, when I run the `./configure` script, it can't find anything:

```
$ ./configure
loading cache ./config.cache
checking for acc... no
checking for cc... (cached) no
checking for gcc... (cached) no
checking for cc... (cached) no
configure: error: no acceptable cc found in $PATH
```

My PATH seems fine and `cc` and `gcc` are available on my system (I've had `build-essential` installed forever):

```
$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

I looked all over SO but didn't find anything that helped.  Any tips?

**UPDATE**

I found that if I set the `CC` environment variable, we get around the first problem, but more are arising.  I'll try to work through them one at a time, but if anyone can point out something major I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.

```
$ CC=/usr/bin/gcc ./configure
loading cache ./config.cache
checking for acc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking for cc... (cached) /usr/bin/gcc
checking for gcc... (cached) /usr/bin/gcc
checking whether the C compiler (/usr/bin/gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (/usr/bin/gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /usr/bin/gcc -E
checking for AIX... no
./configure: 957: ./configure: AC_HPUX: not found
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking for POSIXized ISC... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for complex.h... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for varargs.h... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working const... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
computing machine epsilon(s)
/usr/bin/gcc -o macheps dmacheps.c
dmacheps.c:37:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^
/usr/bin/gcc -o macheps fmacheps.c
fmacheps.c:37:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^
computing M_MAX_INT
/usr/bin/gcc -o maxint maxint.c
maxint.c:27:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^
maxint.c: In function 'main':
maxint.c:37:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%d\n", old_i);
     ^
maxint.c:37:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
maxint.c:37:5: note: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'printf'
checking char \0 vs. float zeros
checking for bcopy... yes
checking for bzero... yes
./configure: 1697: ./configure: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Comment: Do you need Abednego too, and Shadrach?

Comment: Remove `config.cache`; it records that you've not got a C compiler, even though you've installed one recently.  Then rerun the configure script.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did this, but to no avail, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the configure errors (adding `CC=/usr/bin` a few methods needed types in the declarations, etc.).

But then the build had about a hundred warnings/errors, and I noticed the non-standard and potentially illiberal third clause of the license in the files, so I abandoned it and am going to go with a different matrix library instead.